# Hibernate - how to stop schema dropping?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Any `ddlAuto` causes it.

Other stackoverflow topics gives no response, how to fix this.

This profile used - 100 times checked active:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      javax:
        cache:
          missing_cache_strategy: create
        persistence:
          sharedCache:
            mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE
      hibernate:
        ddlAuto: validate
```

Comment: should it not be ddl-auto instead of ddlAuto?

Comment: thanks, will check tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

Long answer is short you mistyped the config key. Use **ddl-auto** instead of ddlAuto.

> Any ddlAuto causes it.

Yes but no. If the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` didn't set explicitly it will have a default value. Basicly the default value is: `none`. But there is a special case. According to the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties)

> The spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto is a special case, because, depending on runtime conditions, it has different defaults. If an embedded database is used and no schema manager (such as Liquibase or Flyway) is handling the DataSource, it defaults to create-drop.

So if you use an embedded database and **ddl-auto** property wasn't set (it wasn't in your case) the default approach will be `create-drop`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following property: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` (instead of `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddlAuto`).
Or even use vendor independent property `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false` to disable DDL generation at startup.

Also, in `@DataJpaTest` by default an application data source is replaced with the test data source. To use in tests the same data source the application uses, set property `spring.test.database.replace=none` or annotate test class with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)`.